GIF size limit is extremely small and easy to hit; increase it to allow for more practical uploads

Current limitation: One cannot upload animated GIF images with over 50 million overall pixels (resolution times frames).
Feature request: Allow GIF animated images with over 50 million pixels.
Motivations:

The 50 million pixel limit is extremely easy to hit. As an example, a 500-by-500 animated image that runs at 20 frames per second and is 10 seconds long already approaches the limit.
Many animated GIFs already uploaded on the network that are not high resolution are above the 50-million-pixel limit (this example has ~100 million pixels).

It makes no sense to force animated GIF images to be of much lower resolution than still images, or so short that it's barely animated.

It makes no sense to limit animated GIF images based on pixel count instead of file size.

Using a third-party host such as Imgur or YouTube is not a good idea, as it leads to link rot (e.g., see the ImageShack debacle that led to the destruction of billions of images, or simply a user deleting their Imgur/YouTube/etc. account or some images/videos). Also, it typically doesn't indicate under which license the image is under, which will make it impossible to fork Stack Exchange if needs be one day. Lastly, some networks (e.g., some firms) don't let their users access Imgur/YouTube.





I don't think this is really needed. For so many frames, one can use external host e.g. imgur, or even making a video. As for the reasoning, it's explained in this answer already. I don't think SE has to change the tools being used just to allow huge GIF animations.

@ShadowWizard using external hosts will result in broken images once the host disappears, and it makes the GIF license unknown (eg, can't fork SE while keeping such images). The given reasoning is technical, while this feature request is from a user standpoint. An animated GIF  image with over 50 million pixels doesn't have to be huge: the pixel count goes up quickly in the animation last a few seconds, isn't overly choppy and isn't
thumbnail sized

Most of the time (nearly all the time) it makes no sense to dump a 50 megapixel GIF into my browser.

Which site(s) do you believe would benefit from such a change?

@JonCuster how about a 10-second GIF with 500x500 resolution and 20 FPS?

@JonCuster any site where an animated GIF can improve an answer.

@Franck some hosts aren't going to disappear any time soon, at least surely not before SE itself. E.g. imgur, YouTube (for video) etc.

@ShadowWizard that's what people thought when using ImageShack, then one day ImageShack swapped these images to some ads https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2386/22303. Sometimes, the users and the image/video themselves can be removed for whatever reason, e.g. the user deleting their own account. And why would Stack Exhange host images but reject animated gif with similar file size? Lastly you haven't addressed the license issue that uploading images to a third party site causes.

The history of the internet shows that, while an animated GIF may be informative to someone else, it rarely actually is.

@JonCuster sometimes it's more efficient to convey some info via animated GIF eg how to do sth in a GUI. (example) There are over 220k GIF images on SE, so I guess some people find them useful.

I agree that, every once in a while, an animated GIF is actually a good thing. However, history shows that most of the animated GIFs on the internet are not useful, so limiting the damage should take a higher priority than allowing the one-in-a-million brilliant GIF.

@JonCuster "history shows that most of the animated GIFs on the internet are not useful" ok but we're on stack exchange here, not Facebook or some cat meme site

@testing-for-ya the example I showed is twice more than the limit. Removing a few frames or cropping it a bit wouldn't have helped.

@testing-for-ya you didn't just crop but you've also moved elements around to make it fit. Which is easy to do on one static image as you've done, but more difficult to do on an animated gif (and unsurprisingly, you've only modified one frame and not the entire gif. 2 minutes for one frame, great!)

Does the same limit apply to APNG images?

@user3840170 looks like it doesn't. So this means you can just convert the gif to apng format, without scaling, and it can be uploaded. Bug or not? Can't really tell. Also, adding this to my answer.

If anything, a browser-based tool to make images SE compatible would be pretty great and idc if it's riddled with ad banners. For not I am very unsure on how I could output a SE-compliant GIF file even using professional tools like Photoshop (duration? Pixel size? frame rate? A merry mix of all this? Asking for help online should never be this complicated)

@JonCuster literally any SE site where users are asking about software or visual-related workflows; blender, graphic design, photography, movies and TV, in these communities people need to show each other what they're talking about to expect any kind of relevant help, describing the way a menu or app works will not do the job

As a response to "just use Imgur or YouTube"
Imgur
In the past I used ImageShack to store some images. Thinking they would never go away. Well, they went away. I only got to recover some of the images and they were severely resized.
I then moved on to Imgur. As of May 2023 (so, last year), Imgur seem to be taking steps to restrict what is on there and what can be there. For now, the restrictions are fairly minor but still impactful:

Anonymously uploaded images are subject to eventual deletion.
Images uploaded with an account are not, as long as the account is "active". At the moment, this is a generous definition - you have to log in once a year. But if you do not, then the account is subject to deletion along with the content.

These are the restrictions I know about. Yet, I also find it troubling that I cannot find a policy for image retention in their help pages. On Web Applications, there is a question How long does Imgur store uploaded images? which has three answers

The top answer (posted April 2015) claims images are there "Forever" and quotes a help article. That article no longer exists, the link is dead.
The next answer from February 2017 says that images should get 1 view every 6 months and cites the Imgur blog. A blog that seems to no longer exist. Not the blog article - the entire blog seems to be gone: visiting https://blog.imgur.com/ (there is a link to it in Imgur's help pages) just redirects to https://imgur.com/.
The newest answer from April 2023 mentions the policy change from last year. It also links to a help article that does not exist.

Also, consider that Imgur's change of policies is why Stack Exchange had to abandon it. From Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur has ended - migration complete!

Imgur no longer provides an enterprise image hosting product, and therefore, it has come time to find an alternative solution.

I no longer trust Imgur to be a viable long-term storage of images.
It is entirely possible there would be more restrictions added in the future. I expect it to happen.
This is just about Imgur as a storage solution. There is a whole other topic around it being external storage solution - all external hosts might be inaccessible for any reason, like being blocked by firewalls, institutions, ISPs, or even China. Yes, Imgur being blocked has already been an issue.
Proposing to use Imgur is a step back in terms of accessibility. And probably at least one additional step back in terms of reliable image retention.
So, avoiding external hosts is very relevant.
YouTube
YouTube is less than ideal, either. It has an infamously byzantine content rules system and many videos have been taken down via automated false DMCA claims. Or forced to be monetised a copyright-but-not-really holder.
Moreover, if you link a YouTube video, you have to expose the account that uploaded the video (Imgur at least separates uploaded content from accounts). I am not a fan of that. I think there might be upload restrictions for new accounts, so throwaway accounts might not be viable, either.
There are other more practical technical issues with compression. As far as I am aware, YouTube imposes video compression for any uploaded content. This does not have to be bad but it is also a known weakness of the platform. Particularly "same-y" frames may get blurred and have compression issues making them hard to see.
There is no shortage of such content on YouTube. It does not make videos impossible to read but quite hard. Also, the blurring may be particularly bad for few seconds. And we are talking about very short videos. I suspect some not-insignificant amount of uploaded videos might be hard to make out for maybe half the length.
I cannot guarantee that would be the case. However, I have come upon enough short videos of somebody's monitor that are hard to make out that I expect it would affect users who try to upload their short videos there.
Should we really shoo away users to other services?
We should take a step back and consider "just go use another service" in more perspective. That involves jumping through a non-trivial amount of hoops. For a 10-ish second video. Because that is the type of content that gets blocked by the 50 megapixel restriction.
I certainly would rather not try to jump through extra hoops, for something that small. And I have not. Multiple times I tried to record some bug that happens on the SE sites. And multiple times I was stopped by the 50 megapixel restriction because I took a short (~10 seconds) video of something about the size of a post (far from a full screen). I found one example that is over 50 megapixels: 12 seconds, 901x803px, 244KB. It barely shows a part of a post and the browser console, so they are visible together. I might have been able to squeeze it a bit more but I could not be bothered.
I have discarded videos and the reports that required it.
I no longer trust Imgur as an image host. I am not uploading on YouTube. And I do not want to search for yet another image uploading service that respects privacy, content retention, ease of use, accessibility, and more.
So, even if alternatives exist I find it simpler to not use them. I do not think it is up to the users to find new and creative ways around the arbitrary1 restrictions of the new uploader. Yes, I am aware it has been justified by SE. However, it is a new and restriction that boils down "sorry, can't be bothered. Figure it out". Well, I do not think I can be faulted if I have the exact same response.

ImageShack was a massive debacle that some people seem to have already forgotten.  See the CEO claiming "We have about 350 servers. About 2 petabytes worth of disk space. Combined hit rate to our sites is about 250,000 queries concurrent. There about 25 billion files stored on ImageShack. Images expire after a year of inactivity, unless they are in your account, in which case they never expire.". And now, it's gone. Countless (dozens of millions?) of posts destroyed or badly impacted due to it.

Good points re Imgur, I'd just add that there are also security concerns from using external image hosts (although to be fair, browsers have mitigate some of those since I wrote that answer) and we should discourage their use, not encourage it. Folks suggesting using YouTube seems weird, since that UX is meant for videos that are minutes long, not seconds...

I agree with this.
Based on the comments, it appears that many people are reading this and assuming that this request would allow for huge animated GIFs. However, this is in fact not the case: the count refers to the overall count of pixels in the entire animation (e.g., two frames of one animation count twice toward the limit).
The other answer here suggests that people simply use an external host for such images. However, this isn't a desired option, because external image hosts can be blocked in local work or school networks (in fact, both websites linked in the answer were blocked in my school, leaving me unable to view almost all images on the network during my early years), such links would be vulnerable to link rot, and it would also leave open questions about content licensing. There's also a highly-voted feature request asking that SE no longer allow embedding externally-hosted images for security and privacy reasons. I feel that the general principle we use to disallow link-only posts also applies here: all info should be in the post itself rather than behind links.
I understand that many people may not find use for embedding animated GIFs that have a high number of frames, but they are definitely useful here on my home site to show reproductions of bugs, and I can also see a use on, say, Super User, to show things not working with other computer applications.
As such, on balance, and considering the large number of animated GIFs exceeding the size limit that were allowed to be uploaded before the image host transition, I think the limit should be raised to at least 100 million pixels. Ideally, the best thing to do would be to go through the currently-uploaded animated images on the former Imgur database and use statistics from there to set an appropriate limit.

"I think the limit should be raised to at least 100 million pixels" why not limit solely based on file size?

@FranckDernoncourt More or less because I'd prefer to see the limit gradually ramped up in steps, so as to assuage concerns that a sudden increase would make animations way too annoying. There are also the previously-raised concerns about the CSAM checkers SE uses having the 50-million pixel limit, and a simple increase to 100 million pixels would only require SE to split images over said limit in half and run the systems only twice.

Before the image host change, the limit solely based on file size. Did that create any major issue?

What tools exist to count the overall number of pixels in an animation? What free tools exist to remove 50 or 100 pixels from a GIF? Did SE provide their users with these answers?

While there is a point in this request, I don't think this is really needed, or at least it doesn't justify the cost.
What cost? As written by SE developer in this answer:

The limitations are mostly imposed by third-party systems we use during the image upload process, and also when resizing animated gifs.

So the cost is to find other third-party tools for the upload process, and since it appears to work just fine now, better not change it.
Turns out that those tools have no problem dealing with .apng animations even if having over 50 megapixels (example using the GIF in the question) so alternative way that does not require scaling the gif or finding external host is to convert the gif to .apng format. There are also online tools for that, e.g. this one.
There are also external hosts, however each has its own downsides.

imgur: can easily host large GIF animations, and isn't going down any time soon so no risk of image rot.
YouTube: can host video showing the screen record, and there are also free online tools to convert any GIF animation to video file that can be hosted on YT.


Imgur has changed its policy and doesn't necessarily keep an image forever. Annoyingly, I can't seem to find anything about it on Imgur's site itself. However this answer on Web Applications SE claims that anonymously uploaded images are subject to eventual removal. The cited date is a year ago: May 2023. The link is dead though. Users can very well prefer to not use an account for Imgur, in which case "just upload to Imgur" is not a good solution. The same can apply to YouTube.

External websites can be blocked by one's school or work ISP. For example, both sites you link to are blocked in most schools.

Also, on a side not - Imgur's change of policies is related to why SE moved away from using it as a service.  The new uploaded announcement says that Imgur no longer provides enterprise hosting solution. There were more changes (that I'm honestly not very familiar with) in Imgur to try and prevent a lot of content. Dropping old uploads, preventing some new ones, as well. That all happened in the same period last year.

@testing-for-ya Sonic raise a valid point, sstatic isn't known and there's no reason to block it. imgur on the other hand is known to host rather explicit images, linked from various places.

Follow-up about APNGs: Animated PNGs (APNGs) become static if over 2 MiB when using the image uploader

@Franck true, but unrelated to the gif size (in mega pixels) limit. It happens because once the uploaded image cross 2 MiB, it triggers something that resize it until it's less than this limit, and that something doesn't support animation. It used to just reject such images before.
